# Assets using targets with Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm working with an iOS app with múltiple targets and at this moment, I have a critical doubt.

The project has two targets, target A and B, and each  target has different set of images.
My question is:
If I upload the target A to iTunes Connect, this target will contain also  the images of the target B, or this target (A) only will contain her images?

Comment: It depends if the assets are part of the same catalogue or not and what is configured to be copied into the app bundle.  If you look at the target's build settings you can see what is copied.

Comment: Ok, I will investigate about that

Answer (score 0):

Target A and Target B would have the same images only if you set it up as such. Each target can have its own set of source files and assets. If you look select items (whether it be source files, frameworks, or other asset files) and have the File Inspector on, you'll see something called Target Membership. This indicates which target it belongs to.

When you Add File(s), there is also a dialog that indicates which targets to add it to.

The Build Phase of the target will also show you the files that are compiled as well as files that are copied into the binary and the libraries used to link.

Note there are multiple ways to add/remove files from the target.